# Text overflow in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I recently joined this wonderful world and I am trying to solve this problem. I have created a table with tabularx, but the text inside it overflows below. How can I solve this problem? I searched for a similar post but I couldn't find any working solution. Is it possible to resize the height of each (multi)row to fit the text in, while still keeping the text vertically centered? Thanks in advance.

[image: The problem]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { 
    | >{\raggedright\footnotesize\arraybackslash}X 
    | >{\raggedright\footnotesize\arraybackslash}X 
    | >{\raggedright\footnotesize\arraybackslash}X 
    | >{\raggedright\footnotesize\arraybackslash}X 
    | >{\raggedright\footnotesize\arraybackslash}X 
    | >{\raggedright\footnotesize\arraybackslash}X 
    | >{\raggedright\footnotesize\arraybackslash}X 
    |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Associazione} &
    \textbf{Descrizione} &
    \textbf{Entità coinvolte} &
    \textbf{Cardinalità Min/Max} &
    \textbf{Molteplicità} &
    \textbf{Attributi/ tipo} &
    \textbf{Descrizione attributi} \\ \hline
    \endhead
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Apertura} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Rappresenta quali Ticket il Cliente ha aperto} &
    Cliente &
    (1, N) &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{uno a molti} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Data apertura: data} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Data in cui il Ticket è stato aperto} \\ \cline{3-4}
      &   & Ticket & (1, 1) &   &   &   \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Riparazione} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Rappresenta quale Dispositivo è coinvolto nella riparazione} &
    Dispositivo &
    (0, N) &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{uno a molti} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{} \\ \cline{3-4}
      &   & Ticket & (1, 1) &   &   &   \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Accesso} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Rappresenta Utenti possono accedere ad un Ticket} &
    Utente &
    (1, N) &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{molti a molti} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{} \\ \cline{3-4}
      &   & Ticket & (1, N) &   &   &   \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Gestione} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Rappresenta quali Ticket un Punto di Accettazione ha in gestione} &
    PDA &
    (0, N) &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{uno a molti} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{} &
    \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{} \\ \cline{3-4}
      &   & Ticket & (1, 1) &   &   &   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always try to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will make getting help easier and effective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of the `tabularray` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\noindent
{\footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{7}{X}}, row{1} = {font=\bfseries}, hlines, vlines, vspan=even, leftsep=3pt, rightsep=3pt} 
    Associazione &
    Descrizione &
    Entità coinvolte &
    Cardinalità Min/Max &
    Molteplicità &
    Attributi/ tipo &
    Descrizione attributi \\ 
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Apertura &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Rappresenta quali Ticket il Cliente ha aperto &
    Cliente &
    (1, N) &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}uno a molti &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Data apertura: data &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Data in cui il Ticket è stato aperto \\ 
      &   & Ticket & (1, 1) &   &   &   \\ 
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Riparazione &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Rappresenta quale Dispositivo è coinvolto nella riparazione &
    Dispositivo &
    (0, N) &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}uno a molti &
    \SetCell[r=2]{} &
    \SetCell[r=2]{} \\
      &   & Ticket & (1, 1) &   &   &   \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Accesso &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Rappresenta Utenti possono accedere ad un Ticket &
    Utente &
    (1, N) &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}molti a molti &
    \SetCell[r=2]{} &
    \SetCell[r=2]{} \\
      &   & Ticket & (1, N) &   &   &   \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Gestione &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}Rappresenta quali Ticket un Punto di Accettazione ha in gestione &
    PDA &
    (0, N) &
    \SetCell[r=2]{}uno a molti &
    \SetCell[r=2]{} &
    \SetCell[r=2]{} \\
      &   & Ticket & (1, 1) &   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to center vertically the header too?

Comment: `row{1} = {font=\bfseries, valign=m},` instead of `row{1} = {font=\bfseries},` should also vertically center the text in the first row.

Comment: Man you are great, thank you again